# Wrong returned position value

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to link pushbuttons using a line that I draw using the paintEvent function, but it's returning wrong values when reading the position of the buttons. this stuff has been tried on simpler projects and it worked but when using several widget container things gets wrong I don't know why.

Image of project result:

[image]

Simpler projects:

[image]

code's header file:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QPainter>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

    virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

code's source file:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QPainter paint(this);

    QPen pen;

    pen.setColor(QColor(56, 163, 220));
    pen.setWidth(2);

    paint.setPen(pen);

    int xstart1 = ui->pushButton_4->pos().x() + ui->pushButton_4->width();
    int ystart1 = ui->pushButton_4->pos().y() + (ui->pushButton_4->height() / 2);
    int xfinish1 = ui->pushButton_6->pos().x();
    int yfinish1 = ui->pushButton_6->pos().y() + (ui->pushButton_6->height() / 2);
    paint.drawLine(xstart1, ystart1, xfinish1, yfinish1);

    int xstart2 = ui->pushButton_5->pos().x() + ui->pushButton_5->width();
    int ystart2 = ui->pushButton_5->pos().y() + (ui->pushButton_5->height() / 2);
    int xfinish2 = ui->pushButton_7->pos().x();
    int yfinish2 = ui->pushButton_7->pos().y() + (ui->pushButton_7->height() / 2);
    paint.drawLine(xstart2, ystart2, xfinish2, yfinish2);
}
```

code's ui:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>590</width>
    <height>435</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
    <item>
     <widget class="QWidget" name="widget" native="true">
      <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2">
       <item>
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
         <property name="text">
          <string>PushButton</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_2">
         <property name="text">
          <string>PushButton</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_3">
         <property name="text">
          <string>PushButton</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item>
        <spacer name="verticalSpacer">
         <property name="orientation">
          <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
          <size>
           <width>20</width>
           <height>268</height>
          </size>
         </property>
        </spacer>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
      <item>
       <widget class="QFrame" name="frame">
        <property name="frameShape">
         <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="frameShadow">
         <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
        </property>
        <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_2">
         <item>
          <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_3">
           <item>
            <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_4">
             <property name="text">
              <string>PushButton</string>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item>
            <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_5">
             <property name="text">
              <string>PushButton</string>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
          </layout>
         </item>
         <item>
          <spacer name="horizontalSpacer">
           <property name="orientation">
            <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
           </property>
           <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
            <size>
             <width>183</width>
             <height>20</height>
            </size>
           </property>
          </spacer>
         </item>
         <item>
          <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_4">
           <item>
            <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_6">
             <property name="text">
              <string>PushButton</string>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item>
            <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_7">
             <property name="text">
              <string>PushButton</string>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
          </layout>
         </item>
        </layout>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_2" native="true">
        <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_5">
         <item>
          <widget class="QTableWidget" name="tableWidget"/>
         </item>
        </layout>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_3" native="true">
      <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_6">
       <item>
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_8">
         <property name="text">
          <string>PushButton</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>590</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: [mapToGlobal](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#mapToGlobal) should be used to translate widget coordinate to global screen coordinate.

Comment: didn't work for me or I'm using it wrong... but I did a work around after understanding its behavior and it worked